# Rasterize lines in R: How to assign max value to a cell?

Tags: r, gis, raster, terra, rasterize

#### Problem

**I want to rasterize spatial lines and assign the maximum value of all lines that touch/intersect a raster cell to that cell.**

I work in `terra` with lines as a `SpatVect` object, I would hence prefer a `terra::rasterize` solution. I would also be happy with a solution using `stars::st_rasterize` (see also [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432367/how-to-apply-mean-min-max-merge-functions-on-a-vector-layer-to-create-a-stars-ra) question).

The [documentation of `terra::rasterize`](https://rdrr.io/github/rspatial/terra/man/rasterize.html) seems to suggest it does not support lines properly so far - using the `fun` argument seems to be limited to points vector data only. I tried with `terra::rasterize` nevertheless, see the example below.

I'm aware of [`raster::rasterize`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.5-15/topics/rasterize), but it seems a bit outdated since it's still `sp` object based. Or is it the only way to do it atm?

#### Example

Here you can see that neither the `max` nor the `mean` function seems to work properly when rasterizing via `terra::rasterize(... fun = "max"/"mean")`:

```
library("terra")

### Example data ###
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
lns <- as.lines(v)
r <- rast(v, res=.2)

### Rasterize via terra::rasterize ###
x_max <- rasterize(lns, r, fun="max", field = "POP")
x_mean <- rasterize(lns, r, fun="mean", field = "POP")

### Plot results ###
fontsize <- 0.7
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(lns, y = "POP", main = "Lines with original values")
text(lns, "POP", cex = fontsize)
plot(x_max, main = "Rasterized via fun 'max'")
text(x_max, cex = fontsize)
plot(lns, add = T)
plot(x_mean, main = "Rasterized via fun 'mean'")
text(x_mean, cex = fontsize)
plot(lns, add = T)
```

[image]

Comment: You can also omit `fun = ` and get exactly the same result. Seems like the documentation is correct - only used if `x` consists of points. What about a workaround like `p <- as.points(lns)` and use these as input to `rasterize()`? Might work in this case, considering the resolution of your raster and the complexity of the geometry used.

Comment: Eventually in combination with an increase in node density along the lines using `rgeos::gInterpolate()` on a `sp` object?

Comment: My real world data is far more complex (44 000 lines, raster with 700 000  cells). I just used this simple example for repex purposes.

Comment: Complex (in terms of nodes per grid cell) would've been good for `as.points()` but I assume you meant quantities only. However, `rgeos::gInterpolate()` might still work here when neglecting performance issues.

Comment: It worked, performance was not an issue. I used `sf::st_line_sample` instead of `rgeos::gInterpolate`. Thanks @falk-env! Oh and you were right, by complex by meant quantities only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a somewhat hacky solution.
As proposed in the comments, I **turned the lines into points by sampling along them**.

I used `sf::st_line_sample()` for this instead of `rgeos::gInterpolate()` - it was cleaner and easier. Then `terra::rasterize()` can handle the points correctly and applies the `max` fun as expected.

Confirmed by the plot below.

#### Example solution

```
library("terra")
library("dplyr")
library("sf")
library("units")

### Example data ###
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
lns <- as.lines(v)
r <- rast(v, res=.2)

### Turn SpatVector lines into sf object
lns_sf <- lns %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  st_transform(2169) # reprojection needed for st_line_sample

### Sample points along all lines every kilometer
pts_geometries <- lns_sf %>% 
  st_line_sample(density = units::set_units(1, 1/km))

### Add attributes and make MULTIPOINTs simple POINTS
pts_sf <- st_sf(lns_sf,
                geometry = pts_geometries) %>% 
  st_cast("POINT") %>% 
  st_transform(crs(lns))

### Go back to terra: Turn sf into SpatVector object
pts <- pts_sf %>% 
  vect()

### Now rasterization works and "max" function is applied corretly
x_max <- rasterize(pts, r, fun="max", field = "POP")

fontsize <- 0.7
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(lns, y = "POP", main = "Lines with original values")
text(lns, "POP", cex = fontsize)
plot(x_max, main = "Rasterized with fun 'max' using points generated from lines")
text(x_max, cex = fontsize)
plot(lns, add = T)
plot(pts, main = "Points used for rasterization")
```

[image]